# How can I reference a resource in a separate ResourceDictionary in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml

In my project (ABC), I have MainWindow.xaml where I have defined a toolbar for it and this toolbar is defined in 
project under Resource/Views/ApplicationToolbar.xmal as following:

I have referenced it in my MainWindow.xaml as  `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ABC"` and as soon as I run it I get an 
error indicating View123 not found.

More information: (EDIT)

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ABC">

    <StackPanel x:Key="View1">
        <Button Margin="3" Content="Test1"></Button>
        <Button Margin="3" Content="Test2"></Button>
    </StackPanel>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Now in MainWindow.xmal have:

```
<Window x:Class="ABC.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ABC"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- FOLLOWING LINE CAUSING ERROR-->
        <ContentControl Name="Toolbar" Content="{StaticResource View1 }"></ContentControl>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

What am I missing?

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: Can you please show us where you actually reference the control? There is not enough information here to propose a solution.

Comment: You need to specify the actual resource dictionary in your MainWindow.xaml

Comment: @PiotrPtak    what if I don't want to mix it with my MainWindow.xaml?

Comment: "*Why WPF is not very good when it comes to referencing?*": why do you assume it is WPF that is "not very good"? Perhaps you're the one who's not very good when it comes to WPF ;). Don't blame something just because you don't understand it properly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all. OK, I tried what was suggested here and I appreciate Mike and it was close to the solution. What worked for me was adding following tag in *App.xaml*:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/views/ApplicationToolbar.xaml"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

Thanks.
Amit

Answer (score 4):

Since `View1` is referenced in a separate `ResourceDictionary` you need to merge it into the `ResourceDictionary` for this `Window`.

Try adding this to the code just inside your `Window` declaration:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Resource/Views/ApplicationToolbar.xaml"/>
  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</Window.Resources>
```

At this point your `Window` should be able to reference `View1`.

**Note:** I haven't tested this fully in an IDE, so it's possible there could be a slight syntax error or issue with the path.  You may have to format your dictionary URL with a [Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) in order for the reference to resolve correctly.  Resource paths in WPF tend to be a little tricky.